# How to return the value of foreach loop in c++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, boost

I need to take multiple lines of string and then prepends with spaces.

I am using boost::split to split the string and assign the value to a vector. And then inside for-each loop, I add spaces to the vector value.

```
static string test(){

    std::string text = "This is a sentence.\nAnd another sentence";
    string nl = "\n";
    string pad="     ";
    string txt;
    std::vector<std::string> results;

    boost::split(results, text, boost::is_any_of(nl));

    for(string line : results){
      txt = pad + line + nl;
      cout << txt;
    }
    return txt;
  }
```

I should get the return value as below. cout result is correct but the return value txt is unable to get.

```
      This is a sentence.
      And another sentence
```

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code, especially that loop you have.

Comment: Your code is reinitialising `txt` on each loop iteration, by assigning it as a whole.  Try `txt.append(pad + line + nl)`.

Comment: I think to let people really understand their mistakes, we should stop giving solutions for this kind of problems in zero time.
We should let the OP to read and think abount comments like the one from Steve and Some programmer dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having

> ```
>  for(string line : results){
>    txt = pad + line + nl;
>    cout << txt;
>  }
>  return txt;
> ```

the return *txt* is the *last* value of `pad + line + nl` from the loop or an empty string if *results* is empty

Saying

> cout result is correct but the return value txt is unable to get.

probably means you just need to collapse each string and return the result :

```
string r;

for(string line : results){
  txt = pad + line + nl;
  cout << txt;
  r += txt;
}
return r;
```

or something similar may be without *pad*

Comment: Thanks. This return the result I want.

Comment: Or just append to `txt` and `cout` at the end. No need for an additional copy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes I know, I wanted to be close to the original code to helps the OP to understand what is wrong in his solution ;-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you really want to have the simpler code just write and return a literal string, not needed to have all the rest ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
static string test(){
    std::string text = "This is a sentence.\nAnd another sentence\n";
    std::string result = "   " + boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy(s, "\n", "\n    ");
    std::cout << result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can I suppose this is not what the OP wanted to do ? Else no reason to use boost but write/return directly the expected literal string ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your loop:

```
for(string line : results){
  txt = pad + line + nl;
  cout << txt;
}
return txt;
```

resets `txt` on every loop iteration (and you print *that iteration's text* one at a time). You then only have the final iteration's value remaining after the loop.

Instead, *append* to `txt` to keep all values. As a consequence you will also need to hoist the `cout` out of the loop:

```
for(string line : results){
  txt += pad + line + nl;
}
cout << txt;
return txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll show the part of the function where the vector is already built. So the function I'll show is simplified but demonstrates how you can build and return the result string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static std::string test( const std::vector<std::string> &results )
{    
    const std::string pad( "     " );

    std::string::size_type n = 0;
    for ( const std::string &s : results ) n += s.length();

    n += results.size() * ( pad.size() + sizeof( '\n' ) );

    std::string txt;
    txt.reserve( n );

    for ( const std::string &s : results ) txt += pad + s + '\n';

    return txt;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> results = { "This is a sentence.", "This is a sentence." };

    std::cout << test( results );
}
```

The program output is

```
 This is a sentence.
 This is a sentence.
```

To make the code more effective you should reserve enough space for the string `txt`. The loop

```
    for ( const std::string &s : results ) n += s.length();
```

calculates the total size of all strings stored in the vector.

**Note:** You could use the standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in the header `<numeric>` instead of the loop as for example

```
std::string::size_type n = std::accumulate( std::begin( results ), std::end( results ), 
                                            std::string::size_type( 0 ),
                                            []( const std::string::size_type acc, const std::string &s )
                                            {
                                                return acc + s.size();
                                            } );
```

Then you add the length of padding spaces for each string and the length of the character `'\n'`.

Thus all is prepared to build the result string that is returned from the function.

```
std::string txt;
txt.reserve( n );

for ( const std::string &s : results ) txt += pad + s + '\n';

return txt;
```